# Transforming files hangs, stuck on red screen of death

Tags: react-native

The transforming files operation gets stuck at 99% and the project does not get launched in the simulator.

[image: rsod]

I've updated and upgraded React native as per the instructions here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

I've also tried the suggestions in the RSOD.

React Native version: 0.38
Platform: iOS
Operating System: OSX 10.11.16
Xcode: 8.1

Answer (score 0):

It's my experience that the instructions in the RSOD aren't as nuclear as they should be.  This method has yet to fail me, though it's the most elaborate destruction that yeilds the highest success.  I don't think I've had to go further than this.

1. Close down packager, and ALL simulator/emulators
2. Make sure node isn't lurking `killall node`
3. `watchman watch-del-all` - as requested
4. Clear platform specific cache

   i. **iOS** - `rm -rf ios/build/ModuleCache/*`

   ii. **Android** - `rm -rf android/app/build`

   iii. **Android** - `rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/`
5. `rm -rf node_modules/` #DeatTo Node Modules
6. `npm cache clean` Node cache clean
7. `npm i` - start fresh
8. `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*` for some reason this always has to be last
9. *ENJOY!*

Comment: Followed your instructions to the tee, but still the same issue - many thanks anyway.

Comment: Wow!  OK, re-clone your project from github and give that a go.  That will tell you if the cruft is in your project or in memory.   If a fresh new clone fails, then you need to try reseting your simulator and rebooting your computer.

Comment: That didn't work either - I'm going to install a previous version of xcode and see if that fixes it - I can't think of anything else to do.

Comment: So if a fresh pull from github failed and a reboot failed, something is wrong in the code of the project.  There's no place left.
Time to start commenting out large chunks of code.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed. A number of loops had to be jumped through including updating various packages and fixing (hacking) broken dependencies that are particular to the project, so documenting the steps taken would not be useful to anyone else.